Include hostname in crontab MAILFROM?
We have a lot of servers on RHEL8 & RHEL9 and would like to set something like this in crontab:
MAILFROM=cron-$HOSTNAME@ourdomain.com

Problem is that HOSTNAME is not defined in the environment where crontab executes  (it's some bash builtin, I understand).
Also, this syntax is apparently not recognized in crontab:
MAILFROM=cron-$(hostname)@ourdomain.com

Is there any way to include the hostname in MAILFROM,
without hardcoding it in each server crontab, and
without writing some kind of wrapper script?

RHEL uses cronie. Latest version 1.7.2 of cronie enables MAILFROM to be inherited from environment: https://github.com/cronie-crond/cronie.

@Matthias -- still can't figure out where to set the variable. Even if define MAILFROM in /etc/environment and reboot the machine, it still has no effect.

Could you test if MAILFROM=cron-\hostname`@ourdomain.comworks? This entails a validhostname` set on each server though.

@nKn -- I tested it now, and it has the same effect as: MAILFROM=cron-$(hostname)@ourdomain.com -- that is : no effect at all :(

weird, how it can be so hard to achieve something so simple .... :\

man 5 crontab , on RHEL9 says: "Both MAILFROM and MAILTO variables are expanded, so setting them as in the following example works as expected: MAILFROM=cron-$USER@cron.com ($USER is replaced by the system user)" --- even this does NOT work, because $USER is NOT defined in the crontab default-environ -- this is all so darn weird....

From all my trial'n'errors ---- HARD-coding MAILFROM in crontab indeed seems to be the ONLY thing that ACTUALLY WORKS --- so totally bizarre....

@Rop this indeed seems to be an undesired behavior, since the documentation says the opposite. Actually, variables should be expanded. We have implemented a configuration a time ago to include the hostname in the mailfrom but modifying Postfix to do so. If this is your use case and is acceptable to you, I can provide an example configuration for Postfix to rewrite the sender address.

Here there should be an example you can try: you could just put the variable substitution line in the cron command instead of environment setting. Or you can put a placeholder and use another external script to substitute the placeholder with the hostname (hardcoded) or whatever else.

@Hastur ---  yes, that will work fine when the crontab command runs OK --- My use-case is actually abt setting MAILFROM when something goes wrong with the command.  Ex: The crontab-command tries to start a script that does not exists, or is not executable, or outputs some error-msg to stderr.  It's very weird that the man-page specifically gives this example: MAILFROM=cron-$USER@cron.com , while in reality it has ZERO effect.  Any $variable in the MAILFROM expression apparently is invalid and the assignment will be ignored. That's what my testing has shown.

The environment setting lines will not do variable substitution (e.g. PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH) so even the $USER. What about to get around to your problem and put a placeholder in the script for all the servers and then to run a script on each of them that will modify system dependent the email address...?

@Hastur -- "The environment setting lines will not do variable substitution" -- yes, indeed, that's what my testing shows.  I just wonder, how can the man-page say exactly the opposite? :   "Both MAILFROM and MAILTO variables are expanded, so setting them as in the following example works as expected ..."

@Hastur -- "What about to get around to your problem..." --- yes, some kind of workaround, apparently is needed to achieve the effect I want.

Ok another workaround... you send the mail to your local server which forwards it to the final destination (since you have smtp) possibly with some rules... So you can distinguish which machine the message comes from.

Give it a look and try this DATEVAR=date +20%y%m%d_%H%M%S: date seems to be executed without needs of $() or  ` `  . Remember that cron is not a shell script. So maybe you can try to set the variable directly via  hostname or /usr/bin/hostname (if the executable is there).
Something like MAILFROM=/usr/bin/hostname -cron@ourdomain.com... and let me know.
